# Telegraf disable notifications

Tags: javascript, telegraf

I can not find in the docs how to disable notifications in my telegraf bot. Anyone knows how to?

```
ctx.replyWithHTML("Text", { disable_notification: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the [source](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/bafef538c228db581352746539c7ccfacb099b64/src/context.ts#L820) of `replyWithHTML` we'll see:

```js
replyWithHTML(this: Context, html: string, extra?: tt.ExtraReplyMessage) {
    return this.reply(html, { parse_mode: 'HTML', ...extra })
}
```

Here the `extra` object is spread to the `reply` which is [then passed to](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/bafef538c228db581352746539c7ccfacb099b64/src/context.ts#L328) `sendMessage`

---

So your way of passing an extra object, with `disable_notification` as defined by the telegram [`/sendMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) method, is the desired way.